# OnScrollListener как добавлять элементы не снизу recycleview а сверху (то есть скроллинг вверх)

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Делаю чат и необходимо прокручивать сообщения вверх чтобы смотреть старые.

Должно быть что-то вроде: я листаю вверх отправляется запрос на сервак я получаю пачку сообщений и должен добавлять их сверху.

Comment: Параметр `app:stackFromEnd="true"` у `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант добавления элементов в начало массива сообщений не подойдет?

```
msgsArray.add(pos, newMsg);
notifyItemInserted(pos);
```

`msgsArray` - массив сообщений, на который завязан адаптер.

`newMsg` - элемент нового сообщения. В Вашем случае более старого, полученного с сервера.

`pos` - позиция, в которую будет в вставлено сообщение. В Вашем случае - 0.

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо, но у сообщений не правильный порядок из-за получения ответа с сервера

Comment: Если Вам достаточно все сообщения задом наперед размещать, то используйте атрибут android:stackFromEnd в случае XML, либо setStackFromEnd при программном создании RecycleView.

Comment: @grapes можете повернуть коллекцию перед вставкой `Collections.reverse(List<?> list);`

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отсортировать коллекцию в нужном вам порядке на [примере](http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/06/14/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-Java.html) и просто потом обновить данные в адаптере.